# How to print out the String value from a JList

Tags: java, jlist, selectedvalue, listselectionlistener

I have a JList which is a list of names and I want to print out any item that I select from the list.  It sounds simple but I do not know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
final DefaultListModel<String> myNamesList = new DefaultListModel<String>();
final JList list = new JList(myNamesList);

final Object chosenName = list.getSelectedValue();

list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {        
    System.out.println(chosenName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the 
`Object chosenName = list.getSelectedValue();`
line is within the `valueChanged()` method.  Otherwise it will always be the initial selected value.